# Unicode versions of common UNIX text tools to run on Windows

Tags: windows, unix, text, unicode

I can't afford the [MKS toolkit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/) (also think its a bit overkill for my needs).  So I was wondering is anyone knew of the standard set of unix text tools but that can handle unicode files under Windows.

Examples are wc, awk, diff, sort etc.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) tools but have no info on if they can handle unicode.  A quick google says - maybe.

Comment: Thanks. According to my research they don't appear to support UNICODE

Answer (score 1):

While this is a far cry from directly answering your question, have you considered using PowerShell to accomplish many of those same tasks? It is fully unicode aware and supports most any character encoding that .NET does.

Comment: I ask from ignorance - does PS have equivalent tools to awk, sed, and diff?